# Running Supervisord on Ubuntu in Docker

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, nginx, docker, supervisord

I'm trying to use supervisor to start nginx and postgresql on boot of a docker container. Using the following Dockerfile and supervisord.conf files, the aforementioned applications start but moments later stop. Does anyone know what could be wrong? There are no error messages to stderr or system log files.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN mkdir -p /var/www /var/pgsql/data /var/log/pgsql /var/log/nginx
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install curl wget supervisor postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev llvm gcc g++ python3-pip python2.7 pytho
n2.7-dev python-pip git nginx nodejs openjdk-7-jdk build-essential
RUN apt-get -y clean all
EXPOSE 80 8000 8080
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

supervisord.conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:nginx]
command=/bin/bash -c "exec /usr/sbin/nginx -DFOREGROUND"
stdout_logfile=/var/log/nginx/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/nginx/%(program_name)s.log

[program:postgresql]
command=/bin/bash -c "exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/pgsql/data"
stdout_logfile=/var/log/pgsql/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/pgsql/%(program_name)s.log
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but, you might be able to tell supervisord to use logs, in /etc/supervisord.conf under [supervisord] with the following example values logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log logfile_maxbytes=50MB logfile_backup=10 loglevel=error. That may help debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You should:

1. Run supervisord in the foreground use `-n` [option](http://supervisord.org/running.html#supervisord-command-line-options).
2. Use `ENTRYPOINT` instead of `CMD` in [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint).